# Rails routes, problem with custom :action not being recognized, always 'show'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to 'manage' users, instead of 'new' and 'show' users via actions.  The problem is somewhere in routes I suspect, as my link '/users/manage' is being received as an id parameter to 'show' action:

Terminal log of process:

```
Processing UsersController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-06-28 00:31:45) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"manage"}

ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions: create, destroy, index, manage, and update):
```

Here are some **code snippets** of relevant parts:

**users/index.html.erb** (the link created to go to the manage section, i.e. '/users/manage'):

```
<%= link_to('New User', :action => 'manage') %>
```

**users_controller.rb** (supposed to be receiving 'manage' action, but gets 'show' fr om above call:

```
def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  def manage
      @users = User.all
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
    @user = User.new if @user.nil?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
```

Ruby/rails sees **'/users/manage'** as a **':controller/:action/:id'** i.e. **'users/show/1'**.

When using **'/users/manage/1'** to edit a single user, the proper :action (as 'manage') is loaded via the UsersController 'manage' function, and everything is displayed to edit from the manage.html.erb file.  UsersController sees 'manage' and not 'show', correctly, int his case, but only because of the :id being passed making the ':controller/:action/:id' route kick in and work.

**'users/manage', :controller/:action** seems to be the **problem**, **not recognizing 'manage' as a valid :action alone, instead sending is as an :id in 'show'**...

**routes.rb**:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :users
  map.resources :categories
  map.resources :posts
  map.connect ':controller/:action'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Why is the 'show' action being automatically undertaken?  Can I force 'users' and 'manage' in routes to be recognized in the controller as 'manage' and not as 'show'?

Thanks for the help people :)

Peace.

*EDIT*
**rake routes**

```
$ rake routes
(in /home/krnel/sites/rails_projects/simple_blog)
        users GET    /users(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
              POST   /users(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
   categories GET    /categories(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"categories"}
              POST   /categories(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"categories"}
 new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"categories"}
edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories"}
     category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}
              PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"categories"}
              DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"categories"}
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
              POST   /posts(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
              PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
              DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
 manage_users GET    /users/manage(.:format)            {:action=>"manage", :controller=>"users"}
              GET    /users(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
              POST   /users(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
              GET    /users/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
              GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
              GET    /users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                     /:controller/:action/:id           
                     /:controller/:action/:id(.:format)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're never actually mapping a 'manage' action specifically. You *are* however mapping /users, /users/:id, /users/:id/edit and some more (post, put, delete) routes by doing map.resources :users. Check your `rake routes` to find out what exactly you've mapped.

As per your question, in your case you can add a route to user resources as follows:

```
map.resources :users, :collection => {:manage => :get}
```

This will add /users/manage GET route for your action. You can add :member(s) or :collection(s) this way. The difference is that member will be expecting an :id to be provided, while collection won't.

Read more in the rails routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

### The right way

What you probably want to do is create an Admin [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for managing users. Then your users will be accessible through /admin/users, /admin/users/:id, /admin/users/:id/edit, etc. This way you can separate the interface in which you're managing the users from the one where users are editing their own profiles. This is a better practice, because this way you don't need to come up with custom routes like /users/manage. It will provide a CRUD area for administration, unrelated to CRUD area for users themselves.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay :)
Added **map.resources :users, :collection => {:manage => :get}** to routes.rb, I still get same problem as above.

Comment: Edited post, added rake routes if that helps pinpoint the problem. Thx.

Comment: make sure your `map.resources :users, :collection => {:manage => :get}` comes before any other users route declaration.

Comment: In your code it looks like you're trying to find user by `params[:id]` inside your `manage` action. This means, you're expecting a route like /users/:id/manage, and for that you need to use `:member => {:manage => :get}` instead of `:collection =>`.

Comment: Appreciate the namespace solution, definetly, better.  But, how can I get this to work this way?  **Do these three routes conflict?**
/users/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show"
/users/manage(.:format) {:action=>"manage"
/users/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show"

Comment: You probably have duplicate routes because you placed both `map.resources :users` and `map.resources :users, :member => {:manage => :get}` in there. Remove the former. Speaking of namespace, I suggest reading the guide I mentioned. It's very clear and to the point. Basically, it involves using `Admin::UsersController` as your controller class, and adding `namespace :admin` block to your routes. Read up. :)

Comment: Solution: as hakunin suggested, place the new map.resources for the collection of manage as a GET before the other resources.

Comment: Another thing: **link_to('Destroy User', {:action => 'manage', :id => @user}** is being made as **'/users/manage?id=1'**.  I have to fix routes again right?  This time to show **:controller/:action/:id -> /users/manage/1** correct?

Comment: Can I add **GET /users/manage/:id {:action=>"manage", :controller=>"users"}** ?  I added it, but I cant add the HTTP var GET in there, so now it doesnt respond to anything...

Comment: Looks like you're definitely looking for complete CRUD functionality under 'manage' namespace. You should use namespaces for this.

Comment: Yes I know, thanks again.  I'm learning, so I want to know how to fix things even if its the wrong way ;).  Not for real project.  Thanks ;)
Solution is to add the 'member' like you said earlier for :id, and in the link_to add the new path manage_user_path(:id => user), instead of the :action and :id.  Definitely go for the name-space, but I want to know how to do it this way to learn. Thanks hakunin.

Answer (score 3):

You can add routes like below for other GET type actions of a controller -

```
resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'manage'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename your routes, use :path_names hash in your routes like this.

```
map.resources :photos, :path_names => { :new  => 'make', :edit  => 'change' }
```

> This would cause the routing to
>   recognize URLs such as
>
> ```
> /photos/make
> /photos/1/change
> ```
>
> The actual action names aren’t changed by this option;
>   the two URLs shown would still route
>   to the new and edit actions.

See this guide for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it is super late and 2020 but if you by accident duplicate the routes in routes.rb it will give you this weird situation.
For example:
#routes.rb

```
resources :users
...(bunch of other routes declaration later)
resources users do
 collection do
   get :manage
end
```

This will cause that when you try to access GET /users/manage it will go to the :show action. I saw in the screenshot you posted that you have the /users routes listed twice. That's an indicator. Find the simple `resources :users` and delete it and leave the one that has more stuff in it since it's the version you need.